# Combine with month and year column kept in different columns on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I keep the month and year information in different columns as numbers.
I want to go back 12 months on sysdate using these columns.

The table I used below as an example ,
Since we are in the 5th month now, I want to get the data up to the 6th month of last year.

versiyon table :

[image]

So as a result of the query ,
the following result should return.

[image]

First of all, I want to query by combining the year and month columns and going back one year from the current month as a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from versiyon
where lpad(year, 4, '0') || lpad(month, 2, '0') >= to_number(to_char(sysdate - 365, 'yyyymm' ))
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=824adb9f5eab4a1e4b5e77809f66352a)

As MT0 say it will not work for leap years... so you can check if it is leap year or not with case when then end clause and using mod(year, 4) to check. In this demo I have created a situation as it is 2020, to be exact like it is 29th of February 2020. where you can see what I am suggesting in action:

[DEMO2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bc4947250aa978dbda9193dc6741b94e)

Comment: Wow , thanks to you I learned how to use lpad and this method really worked.

Comment: @Hakanözel This will not give the expected answer on 29th February as there are not 365 days in a yeap year.

Comment: Hi @Hakanözel, you are welcome, of course you can see that you do not need lpad for the year because all your years are 4 digits....

Comment: This is going to be slower than using math, especially if your data is of any size. I would send an email if you ran this against a large table on my system. I highly recommend not casting to string and concatenating to pull this off as it's CPU intensive. As MT0 mentioned, the leap year is going to cause problems as well.

Comment: Hi @JNevill DEMO2 not solving the leap year ? Is this not a way to resolve the problem ? Is this answer not useful ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the values to strings and concatenate and then use `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)` to get last year's date (which will get the correct date regardless of whether it is a leap year or not):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   versiyon
WHERE  TO_CHAR(year, 'fm0000') || TO_CHAR(month, 'fm00')
         >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12), 'YYYYMM')
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0ef332fbf3d433878490acd176f461e4)*

Comment: There is a situation like you said in February, I think this way is more logical.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your year and month into an integer form of YYYYMM and compare:

```
SELECT * 
FROM versiyon_table 
WHERE (versiyon_table.year * 100) + versiyon_table.month > (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) * 100) + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
```

Comment: How will this work out in 2021?

Comment: It would work fine for 2021; however, if you had historic dates for 203 AD then it would mix up December 203 AD and February 2031 as they would both be represented as `20312`.

Comment: It would work fine for 3 digit years. Year `203` would be `(203*100) + 2 ` = `20302`. Year `2031` would be `(2031*100) + 2` = `203102`. All in all, this is a better route than casting to string and concatenating. The data is likely already stored as integer, so math is going to be *MUCH* less cpu.